# How to split between two capital letters?

Tags: ruby, regex, split

I have the following array:

```
a = ["CH3", "CH2"]
```

and I'd like to split this between two capital letters using a reg expression to display: `a= ["C", "H3", "C", "H2"]` How do you do this?

so far I've tried:

```
a.each { |array|
x = array.scan(/[A-Z]*/)
puts a
}

returns: 
CH
CH
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does your code say `puts a` instead of `puts x`? And why is your loop variable called `array` when it is a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try this:

```
s.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/)
```